# Cannot extend lvm partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I'm trying to extend a LVM partition on Ubuntu 14.04. As you can see total disk space is 40G however sda3 is only 8.9G. I tried running lvextend but for some reasons the free space is not being picked up.

Thanks for your help.

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0  39.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                     8:1    0   142M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                     8:2    0   954M  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3                     8:3    0     9G  0 part
  └─CAC_VG-CAC_LV (dm-0) 252:0    0   8.9G  0 lvm  /
sr0                       11:0    1   354K  0 rom

root@ubuntu:~# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG CAC_VG   lvm2 [8.93 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [8.93 GiB] / in use: 1 [8.93 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               CAC_VG
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               8.93 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2285
  Alloc PE / Size       2285 / 8.93 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               A4SRwW-Vqpz-qRLf-iXIm-yKny-tcyI-wYTMdg

root@ubuntu:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/CAC_VG/CAC_LV
  LV Name                CAC_LV
  VG Name                CAC_VG
  LV UUID                0DUf2t-XI5Q-Xv8W-f2Yn-uycK-4l0x-A6zI1E
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2014-07-27 16:00:17 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.93 GiB
  Current LE             2285
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

root@ubuntu:~# vgextend CAC_VG /dev/sda3
  Physical volume '/dev/sda3' is already in volume group 'CAC_VG'
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda3' to volume group 'CAC_VG'.

root@ubuntu:~# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/CAC_VG/CAC_LV
  New size (2285 extents) matches existing size (2285 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.

root@ubuntu:~# vgs -o +vg_free_count,vg_extent_count
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree Free #Ext
  CAC_VG   1   1   0 wz--n- 8.93g    0     0 2285
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `lvresize` to work you must first extend the `sda3` partition which holds the LVM physical volume:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 3 -1
```

This will resize `/dev/sda3` to occupy all the space available on the disc. (`resizepart 3 -1` means "move the end of partition number 3 to the last sector on the disc".)

You may want to boot from the installation media into a live session, in order to avoid any problems with mounted file systems.

Comment: @Gnad: If the answer solved the problem then please accept it to indicate that is was correct, so that future readers will know.

Comment: Okay done. Sorry I was new to stackexchange.