# Extend LVM size

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, root, lvm

I recently cloned my ubuntu from a 250GB SSD to my new 2TB SSD.  It automatically created an LVM with 248GB with my root filesystem in it.

I would like to resize the LVM to full 2TB.

```
nvme0n1             259:1    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1         259:7    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2         259:8    0   1.8T  0 part 
  ├─vgubuntu-root   253:0    0 231.4G  0 lvm  /
  └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

However the PSize is only 250 GB, rather than 2TB from`sudo pvs`

```
PV             VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 vgubuntu lvm2 a--  232.38g    0
```

I see the following output from `lvdisplay`:

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                0wM6pq-o26o-qVBf-1x61-vFbP-Poyf-fFW3f7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2021-04-24 06:13:08 +0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <231.43 GiB
  Current LE             59246
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

I tried the following `lvextend` command but it does not extend beyond 248GB size:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vgubuntu/root/
```

with the output:

```
New size (59246 extents) matches existing size (59246 extents).
```

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1406697/edit) your question and add the output of `lvdisplay`?  A lot of the time the lvname is different than what you see when you run like `lsblk` or `df`.  What we are looking for is the name associated with `LV Path`.

Comment: Hi Terrance, done. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please do one more edit and add the output of `vgdisplay vgubuntu`?

Comment: Ah, I also missed something here.  Your `pvs` states 0 free space.  You need to extend out `nvme0n1p2` partition size.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/877743/cannot-extend-lvm-partition?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Terrance. I just reinstalled my Ubuntu yesterday and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like what you need is growpart. I'm not sure which steps you already did. Here is what I did on a similar machine:

Before storage expansion, this is what I have

```
root@agw:~# lsblk /dev/vda
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
vda                  252:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─vda1               252:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─vda2               252:2    0  513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─vda3               252:3    0 19.5G  0 part 
  ├─vgxubuntu-root   253:0    0 18.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─vgxubuntu-swap_1 253:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  
root@agw:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vgxubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- 19.49g    0
```

I added 2G to the underlying disk. You'll see vda now has 22G of space, while vda3 is not automatically using all the space.

```
root@agw:~# lsblk /dev/vda
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
vda                  252:0    0   22G  0 disk 
├─vda1               252:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─vda2               252:2    0  513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─vda3               252:3    0 19.5G  0 part 
  ├─vgxubuntu-root   253:0    0 18.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─vgxubuntu-swap_1 253:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  
root@agw:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vgxubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- 19.49g    0
```

After expanding vda3, run lvextend and resize2fs (if you're on ext4).

```
root@agw:~# growpart /dev/vda 3
CHANGED: partition=3 start=1054720 old: size=40888287 end=41943007 new: size=45082591 end=46137311

root@agw:~# pvs
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/vda3  vgxubuntu lvm2 a--  21.49g 2.00g

root@agw:~# lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/vgxubuntu/root
  Size of logical volume vgxubuntu/root changed from <18.54 GiB (4746 extents) to <20.54 GiB (5258 extents).
  Logical volume vgxubuntu/root successfully resized.
  
root@agw:~# df -hPT /
Filesystem                 Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root ext4   19G   11G  7.2G  59% /

root@agw:~# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 3, new_desc_blocks = 3
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root is now 5384192 (4k) blocks long.

root@agw:~# df -hPT /
Filesystem                 Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root ext4   21G   11G  9.1G  53% /
```

Comment: Works for me, but a little change.  `/dev/vda` -> `/dev/sda`, `/dev/vgxubuntu/root` -> `/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`, `/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-root` -> `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

Answer (score 3):

You are close to extending it.  The name we were looking for is what the `LV Path` states from the command of `lvdisplay`.  `LV Path` shows the name as `/dev/vgubuntu/root`.

The command to extend it should be:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vgubuntu/root
```

Comment: Yes I tried the name `/dev/vgubuntu/root` too. It showed the same output which could not extend beyond the 250GB size: `New size (59246 extents) matches existing size (59246 extents). `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pvresize`

In this case `pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p2`

Then you should be able to resize the lv using the method you employed.