# Partition in another partition too small

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, filesystem, ext4

So I've got a problem with a partition in a partition. Disk hierarchy:

[image: Disk hierarchy screenshot]

My disk (nvme0n1) is partitioned into 3 parts.

1. /boot/efi 512M (nvme0n1p1)
2. /boot 1G (nvme0n1p2)
3. *no name* (nvme0n1p3)

`nvme0n1p3` has a "subpartition" named `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` (200G) which is mounted/used under `/`. `nvme0n1p3` is 930G big, but the Ubuntu partition only 200G. Now my question:

**Is there a way to get the remaining 730GB into the ubuntu partition with the terminal, without losing all data?**

The Ubuntu partition is ext4, if that's important. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

*What I tried:*

- [How to merge partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66000/how-to-merge-partitions)
- Using `parted` with the `partresize` command
- Just using `fs2resize`

Output of `sudo pvs`:
`/dev/nvme0n1p3 ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <930.01g <730.01g`

If there are any questions, I'm happy to answer them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo pvs` show for that partition?  You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1406922/231142

Comment: You need to extend your LVM volume. There is a very good guide to this here https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, I fixed my question

Comment: @Terrance Thank you very much, that worked! I will add an answer to my question later, according to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of @Terrance worked.
He pointed out [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406922/231142) from another question, which worked. I did the following steps from the answer:

```
raziel@hanneserver:~$ sudo lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 200.00 GiB (51200 extents) to <930.01 GiB (238082 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.

raziel@hanneserver:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 25, new_desc_blocks = 117
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 243795968 (4k) blocks long.

raziel@hanneserver:~$ df -hPT /
Filesystem                        Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4  915G  181G  696G  21% /
```